# notification alert without unlocking screen on Lollipop

Tags: notifications, 5.0-lollipop

Before my phone got upgraded to lollipop, I was able see that I had a missed call,SMS text, other app notification without having to unlock my screen.

Now I have to unlock my screen just to see if I have any notifications, how do I bring back the old ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Than you have to change notification settings in your android phone.

**GOTO :  Settings > Sounds & Notification > App Notification**

In **Settings > Sounds & Notification**

you can set the all notification setting like , sound , notification light etc.

I hope this help you to solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Sounds & Notification > When device is locked > Show all notification content

Hope this solves your query